# Does the position of Google Analytics snippet within the document head (before or after scripts and css) affect tracking data?

Tags: google-analytics, html, tracking

The MonsterInsights plugin puts the Google Analytics tracking code before other java scripts and stylesheets. I wanted to reduce by one more the number of plugins that I’m using so I put the Google Analytics tracking code into the “Add code to the `<head>` of your blog” of Divi theme options. What I have seen is that Divi puts the tracking code below the stylesheets and some java scripts.

Would that have any implications for tracking data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not.

Providing you don't have anything that is causing long page load times loading before the Google tracking code is fired, then there shouldn't be a problem. If you do have something that might be causing users to abandon the page prior to the GA code registering the page view, then you might see an increase in exits from the page the user was viewing **before** they got the affected page.

All sites are different and if your's is one of the 1% that might be affected would be to compared your Analytics data for that page from before and after this change was implemented.

Comment: If somebody abandons before the `<head>` is done loading, should it really be counted in your stats anyway?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, No it probably shouldn't. But a high rate of exits from that page would be easier to diagnose if they were.